# php function searches an array object for a specific value

Tags: php

I have an array object like this,

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 247 )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 248 )
)
```

From this, is there any function to check `id=222` is present or not.

I tried with `in_array()` and `array_search()`, it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `isset($arr['id'])`. Try **[reading the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**.

Comment: I need to find, given id=222 is exist in the array object or not?

Comment: How can you not know how to do this when you're writing PHP? What about `$arr['id'] == 222`?

Comment: If only there were some way to `loop` through the array....so that `for` each element, you could perform some kind of test to see `if` a condition is true. Bah, that's just a pipe dream...

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with specified callback:

```
$entries = array_filter($arr,
    create_function('$v', 'return $v->id == ' . $id . ';'));

$isPresent = count($entries) > 0;
$firstFound = array_shift($entries);
```